# How to send two bodies of text in a POST request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

What would be the best way to POST two bodies of multiline text to a web server as an AJAX call using JQuery? My initial project only involved sending one body of text. In that case, I simply made the body of the POST request as the body of the text and simply extracted the POST body in the webapp written using Python and webapp2

Now I need to send two bodies of text. Each body of text is basically text from an online plain text editor. Hence, it can contain anything.

Comment: In jQuery you can add the two texts to an object, and send that (it's stil sent as a string), that way you'll have two keys on the server you use to access them.

Comment: What have you tried? You can post as many variables as you want, there's absolutely no technical restrictions that would prevent you from achieving what you want to achieve. Please post what you've tried so we can see where you might be going wrong.

Comment: So you post up two name value pairs....

Comment: @ChristianVarga I will try that. There is no character that a user can type that would throw it off? And all pre-formatted text will make it to the server exactly as it was typed?

Comment: Yes there is, hence why you properly encode the values. An since you are using jQuery, it does it be default with its Ajax requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on my comment, there's no technical restrictions that could possibly prevent what you want to achieve. You simply include the 2 variables in your ajax call.

Assuming you've got the following HTML elements

```
<textarea name="textarea_1"></textarea>
<textarea name="textarea_2"></textarea>
```

Then the following call would send the content of both textareas to your server:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: {
      textarea_1: $('#textarea_1').val(),
      textarea_2: $('#textarea_2').val()
    }
});
```

If you have a form with loads of inputs, you make your life easier by serializing the entire form:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: $('#my-form').serialize()
});
```

Comment: I would assume that the OP will need to change the python server-side code to parse the JSON correctly.

Comment: @GregL I don't see why he would need to do that; the above code sends 2 POST variables to the server. Not JSON.

Comment: @GregL Haha no worries! The `$.ajax` function is really powerful, 90% of the time I use it instead of relying on the browser to refresh the page.